# Create a CSV File with specific Entries

Tags: c#, csv

I have to list all PDF Files in a Directory and create a csv File with the Names of all the PDFs Files in it.

Also there should stand other entries like Creation Date and a Barcode in the CSV File.

The entries should be separated by "#_#".

The CSV File should look like this:

```
Description          Date                  Barcode                          PDFName

SAP_Eingang#_#2014.01.14 12:34:44#_#01001019000516572013#_#01001019000516572013_2014_01_14_12_34_44_662.pdf
SAP_Eingang#_#2014.01.14 12:35:44#_#01001019000516572014#_#01001019000516572014_2014_01_14_12_35_44_662.pdf
SAP_Eingang#_#2014.01.14 12:36:44#_#01001019000516572015#_#01001019000516572015_2014_01_14_12_36_44_662.pdf
```

I have already this Code to list all PDFs in a CSV File:

```
string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\test\", "*.pdf").Select(path =>Path.GetFileName(path)).ToArray();
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\test2\test.csv",fileArray);
```

But I don't know how to write the other entries in the CSV File.

Comment: Where do you get barcode and description of file?

Comment: Ironically the only typo I found to fix was the one apologising for your English!

Comment: The Barcode is a part of the PDF File Name. See "01001019000516572013". And the Description is always the same "SAP_Eingang"

Answer (score 1):

Use DirectoryInfo instead:

```
const string description = "SAP_Eingang";
const string separator = "#_#";


//open csv file in a using statement

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\test\");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.pdf");
foreach(FileInfo fi in files) {
  string[] columns = new string[4];
  columns[0] = description;
  columns[1] = fi.CreationTime.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss");
  columns[2] = fi.Name.Substring(0, 20);
  columns[3] = fi.Name;
  string line = String.Join(separator, columns);

  //write line into the csv file

}

//close the using statement
```

I haven't compiled the above code, but you get the idea

Comment: Looks sensible - being paranoid I'd add some handling in case the filename contains a comma though!

Answer (score 0):

My code is now:

```
using (StreamWriter rdr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test2\test.csv"))
{
  const string description = "SAP_Eingang";
  const string separator = "#_#";

  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\test\");
  FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.pdf");
  foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
    {
      string[] columns = new string[4];
      columns[0] = description;
      columns[1] = fi.CreationTime.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss");
      columns[2] = fi.Name.Substring(0, 20);
      columns[3] = fi.Name;
      string line = String.Join(separator,columns);

      rdr.WriteLine(line);
     }
 }
```